# How should light switches be connected with 5 black and a 2 white wires?

Tags: electrical

I am changing out some light switches and so far things went well and were straight forward with the dimmers, 3 and 4 ways I replaced. However, on my final switches I came across 2 weird light switches that did not work before but I still want to wire them the same way they were onto the new switches to have things the way they were...

Switch 1 has 1 white and 1 black on the same screw while a second black is going to the lower screw.

The other switch has 3 black wires, one goes into the switch without screw, the other to onto the 2 screws on the same side.

This leaves me totally buffeted?????

Any ideas why to do? If it's an EASY SAFE fix I would rather do it myself than have the electrician come out to charge me $200 for a 5 minute job. If it's not of course I will have an electrician come out and do what needs to be done to be safe.

Thanks a ton!

[image]

Comment: DON'T use trial-and-error to do things in electrical.  Use skill.  The problem with trial-and-error is that your "measurement for success" is that it works.  Lots of things which "work" **are also deadly**.

Comment: The reason that's confusing it that it's an illegal bodge job.  The wire is white because it is *cordage* intended for lamps, not in-wall wiring.  It's illegal and unsafe for use inside walls.   Also, 2 wires on 1 screw are a no-no... This house is probably full of bodge jobs like that.   One wire will be ribbed, that's the "white", the other will be smooth, that's the "black". But really, that just needs to be ripped out...

Comment: so as I am not using those anyways and they are not working can't I just clip them off and leave them be with a plate on top rather than a switch? How are light switch wires disconnected if not in use any longer? Thanks!

Comment: Disconnecting them would be a start at removing the non standard wiring, but you should find where this white cordage goes and also disconnect it there.  Then pull the cordage out of the wall. If the cordage is actually powering something that you want powered, you might be able to attach the proper wiring and pull it thorough. Note that there are holes drilled in the side of the  box which compromise the safety barrier that the box is rated for.

Comment: Any wires you clip should be capped with a wire nut, and electrical tape around it to hold it in place if loose (but **not** electrical tape by itself). That is because even though the wires are "dead" now, you don't know what is going on at the other end - i.e., someone else may do something and all of a sound the clipped wires are "live" in a hidden location, which could cause big problems if not properly capped.

Comment: so clipping them, putting nut on them and electric tape in case they are loose will do the trick with a plate on top of them? Should each wire have its own nut to be safe? Sounds like a cheaper and easier fix then looking everywhere as to what they are connected to and then pulling them out etc. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a light in the room that is operated by a switch that *is* working?  That is a Code requirement. You're not allowed to have rooms where you need to grope around in the dark and find a floor lamp.

Comment: Harper, there are switches right next to them that are working. It is a 4 switch plate. One is a dimmer for dining area and one is a 3 way light switch in the kitchen that are both working. Those 2 have not been working since we bought the home and don't seem to have a place as all light switches go to lights that work besides those 2.

Comment: If you clip this cordage on one end ony, be sure that the two conductors are insulated from each other because one may be hot and the other neutral. There are small wire nuts which would screw onto a lone cordage conductor, but a standard yellow or red wire nut will not unless there are other wires in the connection.

Comment: I had lamp cord in my kitchen that was running from a switch to some undercabinet lights.  I pulled that out as one of my first jobs.  Good advice here.

Comment: as Harper stated earlier that the white and the black together are illegal and dangerous should they each get their own nut? I have a lot of nuts so each one can get its own if that makes it safer...

Comment: Regarding the $200 bill: Legend has it that a prominent businessman once balked at paying $10,000 for work done troubleshooting a generator, and asked for an itemized bill. The engineer who performed the work sent this: “Making chalk mark on generator, $1. Knowing where to make mark, $9,999.”

Comment: Well Henry Ford is a billionaire and I am not. I am here to see if there is a safe simple fix to this so I can avoid paying the $200 and it seem like there is. I have my first baby on the way and $200 go a long one way for me. So I want to thank everybody who is actually helping me. It seems like clipping them and putting nuts on them is a perfectly safe solution til I have enough money to have an electron redo the electric of the whole home where it's needed. For now, should every wire have it's own nut just to be save and not get neutral and hot mixed up and insulted from each other?

Comment: @DD34 Yes, cap wires separately, and *do* tape them as wire nuts fall off single wires.  (on the other hand, don't tape 2+ wires, if that needs taping, that's bad technique creating a dangerously bad  connection. Instead, fix the technique!)

Comment: @Harper Thanks a ton! So I will clip all 6 wires and give each one its separate nut and then tape each wire too to make sure the nut will stay on there. Then get a plate on top.  That is a perfectly safe solution for now if all is done correctly?

Comment: OK, where does that lampcord head? It's presence in this scheme is a bad sign....